# Easy way to carve out displacement from Plane

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, displacement

I am trying to trim all of the vertices or faces off around my displacement, which I applied to a plane.  The vertices on the plane are not at 0, so even though they look flat around the main image they aren't completely, they didn't move too much though.  Is there a way to select vertices that are less angled than others?  I tried sharp edges, but I can't select the rest of it, because it starts to select all that I don't want too.  Or maybe a way of conforming the flatter vertices toward the middle?  This image doesn't have alpha.   Just trying to "carve" my image displacement out without a lot of manual work.  Then extrude it to a mesh.  [image: My plane with my image displaced on it]Thanks!